# UBuntu, PHP, NGINX, FastCGI, FPM, CodeIgniter Timeout

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, timeout, fastcgi

I need help on resetting server timeout, at present, the php scripts on my linode servers timeout in 50 seconds, i have tried all options to increase the timeout time but nothing helps.

Environment -

Linode VPS
Server OS - UBuntu 12
Nginx
PHP / Fast CGI
apache

My Development is being done with CodeIgniter

I have a test script (test.php), with the following code -

```
<?php
sleep(70);
die( 'Hello World' );
?>
```

When I call this script through a browser, I Get a 504 Timeout Error.

I have setup the following -

PHP - set max_execution_time to 300, max_input time to 300

updated NGINX Configuration file with all the timeout variables (proxy, fastcgi etc)

Setup FastCGI to timeout after 600 seconds

Still my script timeouts at 50 seconds, i have reloaded nginx, rebooted vps, but the changes are not reflecting.

Please help me, this issue is turning me mad.

Sincerely,

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that your script doesnt read from the configuration file you made the change in. However, this question is better suited for [SERVER FAULT](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Its reading, in php.ini i have set max_execution_time = 3000, but phpinfo displays as 300, but i have also set max_input_time = 3000, which is correctly displayed!

Comment: 3000 milliseconds? That's not much. However, if it doesnt get updated, chances are you're doing it in the wrong place. This is not a code issue though, so you won't find much help here.

Comment: i have changed two variables in php.ini, one is max_execution_time another one is max_input_time, i can see max_input_time changed but not max_execution_time,

Comment: I have fixed the php.ini bug, now i have set max_execution_time = 3000 seconds, phpinfo displays it, i had to change into the fpm directory. now where do i change the timeout setting, in fpm, nginx and php, i have setup timeout as 300 seconds or 5 mins, still it stops in 50 seconds